# drag and drop progress Vaadin and Java

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a Vaadin DragAndDropEvent from [here](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/branches/sampler2/coresamples/com/vaadin/demo/sampler/features/dragndrop/DragDropHtml5FromDesktop.java) but there's something weird about the progress indicator

```
@Override
public boolean listenProgress() {return true;}

@Override
public void onProgress(final StreamingProgressEvent event) {
  Notification.show("De upload is bezig", Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Could someone explain me where I need to put my Notification so that the notification is showed when the upload is in progress and not when it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** put `UI.getCurrent().setPollInterval(10)` before your `progress = new ProgressIndicator();`
line or enable Push Mode.

There are 2 solutions to this problem. You can either stick to `ProgressIndicator` which is used in your sample or use brand new ProgressBar together with Push Mode.

1. Javadoc for ProgressIndicator states:

> @Deprecated
>
> Deprecated. as of 7.1, use ProgressBar combined with
>   UI.setPushMode(PushMode) or UI.setPollInterval(int) instead.

your code does not work because your poll interval is higher (or disabled at all) than time needed for transfer the file.

2. Second, similar approach is to use ProgressBar as suggested in JavaDoc. However, you still need to make sure that either PushMode or PollInterval is set.